# How to validate a checkbox input using PHP?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have two check boxes in my form:

```
<div class="label-input-wrapper pickup">    
        <div class="form-label">I need Airport pick-up</div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="checkbox" name="pick_up" value="Yes" />Yes 
            <input type="checkbox" name="pick_up" value="No" />No
            <div class="error-msg">
                <?php if(isset($errors['pick_up_no'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['pick_up_no'].'</span>'; } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Variable that saves the value of the above check boxes: `$pickup = $_POST['pick_up'];`

Validation:

```
//Check the airport pickup and make sure that it isn't a blank/empty string.
        if ($pickup == ""){
            //Blank string, add error to $errors array.        
            $errors['pick_up_no'] = "Please let us know your airport pick up requirement!";
        }       

        if (($pick_up = Yes) && ($pick_up = No)) {
            //if both selected, add error to $errors array.        
            $errors['pick_up_no'] = "Can not select Yes and No together!";
        }
```

But the above validation just printing `Can not select Yes and No together!` if both are NOT selected, or if only one selected or even both are selected. It gives same error message for all the selections. Why?

Comment: nop.. I just want to use check boxes only.. I like that name @Ghost

Comment: You should treat the values Yes and No as strings - so put quotes around them!

Comment: @Adimeus I've changed to `if (($pick_up = "Yes") && ($pick_up = "No"))` but still the result is same.

Comment: @RatanK I've updated with your code. Now it's showing proper error message if both are NOT selected. It's just not printing nothing if both selected.

Comment: @RiffazStarr Ghost's answer worked (for me). Thought you'd like to know, yet I still feel that radio buttons should be used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you need a checkbox for this (this is what radio button's are supposed to do), but you can do it something like:

```
if(!isset($_POST['pick_up']) || count($_POST['pick_up']) > 1) {
    echo 'please select at least 1 choice';
} else {
    echo $_POST['pick_up'][0];
}
```

Then make your checkbox names:

```
name="pick_up[]"
```

Or if you really need to have separate error messages. Do something like this:

```
$errors['pick_up_no'] = '';
if(!isset($_POST['pick_up'])) {
    $errors['pick_up_no'] = "Please let us know your airport pick up requirement!";
} elseif(count($_POST['pick_up']) > 1) {
    $errors['pick_up_no'] = "Can not select Yes and No together!"; // weird UX, should have prevented this with a radio button
}

if($errors['pick_up_no'] != '') {
    echo $errors['pick_up_no'];
} else {
    echo $_POST['pick_up'][0];
}
```

Comment: I tend to think that this would work, although I haven't tested it yet. OP should give some input if it did or not. I'm right in the middle of something, so I'll come back later to let you know if it does, I will definitely +1  ;) yet I tend to think that radio buttons is a more feasible option as I've noted in my edit. Checkboxes for both yes AND no doesn't make sense, IMHO.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes actually i tested this before posting, but i also agree with your sentiment, this should be a radio button, no doubt, thats weird for a user experience to actually choose both yes and no

Comment: It's boils down to a "wishy washy" decision lol - It's yes **or** no. Pick me up at 8 and don't be late hahaha!

Comment: @Fred-ii- well at heart, really my original answer is the one that utilizes the radio button which is most logical thing to use. anyway, hope the user tries this.

Answer (score 3):

You're presently assigning with a single `=` sign instead of comparing `==` with

```
if (($pick_up = Yes) && ($pick_up = No))
```

you need to change it to

```
if (($pick_up == "Yes") && ($pick_up == "No")){...}
```

while wrapping `Yes` and `No` inside quotes in order to be treated as a string.

---

***Edit:***

Your best bet is to use radio buttons, IMHO.

Using checkboxes while giving the user both Yes and No options shouldn't be used; it's confusing.

It should either be `Yes` **OR** `No` and not ***and***.

```
<input type="radio" name="pick_up" value="Yes" />Yes 
<input type="radio" name="pick_up" value="No" />No
```

That is the most feasible solution.

Comment: I've updated to `if (($pick_up == "Yes") && ($pick_up == "No")) {
   //if both selected, add error to $errors array.        
   $errors['pick_up_no'] = "Can not select Yes and No together!";
  }` but it's just printing nothing if bot are selected..

Comment: I've made an edit with `if (($pick_up == "Yes") || ($pick_up == "No"))` try an `OR` operator @RiffazStarr or see Ghost's answer.

Comment: @RiffazStarr Are you echoing `$errors` somewhere? Just doing `$errors['pick_up_no'] = "Please...` does nothing really without an echo.

Comment: yes I am echoing here `<div class="error-msg">
                <?php if(isset($errors['pick_up_no'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['pick_up_no'].'</span>'; } ?>
            </div>`

Comment: Plus, as Ghost states in his answer, you need to assign both checkboxes as `name="pick_up[]"` to be treated as an array. @RiffazStarr Did you try Ghost's answer in conjunction with mine?

Comment: @RiffazStarr You do have `<form></form>` tags, correct? You may have to post a bit more code for me to test properly.

Comment: It will never print that error message if both are selected, since its impossible for one value to be the both at the same time. 

Either you change the name of the checkboxes to name="pick_up[]" which creates an array containing both yes and no, or you use radiobutton instead of checkboxes which only allows for one to be selected

Comment: @OleHaugset I've noticed that. I've edited my answer, but waiting on OP to post a bit more code so I can test properly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- my code is too lenghty.. Im working on this for a month. You can find the code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59730ca47465e338fd92abd836c57cb72fc8b349 All works fine.. database, sending mail validation all fine except this check box

Comment: @Fred-ii- i don't know the OP is not interested anymore with other answers haha

Comment: @Ghost I've no more time to spend on this right now. OP would be better off using radio buttons, IMHO. Am not sure if OP tried yours. I'll have to come back later to see if I can make it work.

Comment: @RiffazStarr Please consult my **Edit**. I have to tend to other things right now. I hope it serves you well, *cheers.*

Comment: Thanks for your all effort @Fred-ii- I changed check box to radio button as suggested. now it works fine. So I up voted your answer and accept his answer.

Comment: @RiffazStarr You're very much welcome, happy to have helped and thanks. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for $_POST['pick_up'] to be both yes and no at the same time since the name is pick_up and not pick_up[] <- pointing to multiple variables. So it will either be yes or no either way because one parameter will overwrite the other. You would have to use javascript to verify only one is checked before submit in that case.

Comment: Follow this and convert name of checkboxes `pick_up[]` and change like this `if (($pick_up == 'Yes') && ($pick_up == 'No'))`

Comment: Why the ** did i get downvoted on this. My answer is absolutely correct. As his code currently is, it is impossible for the _POST parameter to contain both yes and no at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Use array of checkbox field elements;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pick_up[]" />Yes 
<input type="checkbox" name="pick_up[]" />No
```

then in your PHP script:

```
<?php

$pick_ups=$_POST['pick_up'];

$first=isset($pick_ups[0]); //true/false of first checkbox status
$second=isset($pick_ups[1]); //true/false of second checkbox status

?>
```

Again, as you've already been told, you should use radio-buttons for this purpose! Take into account that $_POST does not send checkbox if it is not set (check with isset($_POST['name'])